# SDK Location on Different Drive

Tags: android, android-studio

Trying to setup a Android Project on one of my external drives.

My Sdk is located on my D: drive
and my project is on E:

Easy enough, but however when I have my local.properties set to that it does not work.

```
sdk.dir = D:\Android_SDK
```

When it attempts to compile it'll look like this:

```
sdk.dir = E:\projectDirectory\D:\Android_SDK
```

Is there a way I can go up a directory like '../' or some sort of way I can tell it to map to the other drive and not the E drive.
Hopefully that is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Open Android Studio

2 - Up, Left corner click File->Settings

3 - Look for Appearance & Behavior -> Android SDK

4 - Click Edit, and browse you SDK location (usually is in :Users\\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk) https://i.stack.imgur.com/twvfC.png

---

Or you can try in some versions:
From Android Studio 1.0.1

Go to

File -> project Structure into Project Structure

Left -> SDK Location

SDK location select Android SDK location (old version use Press +, add another sdk)

and you should find jre version and NDK location as well as SDK to edit. ;)

---

For even older versions (<1.0 of Android Studio):
1. Close current Project (File->Close project)

You'll get a Welcome to Android Studio Dialog. In that:

2. Click on Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure
3. Click on SDK Location in the left column
4. Put the path to the Android SDK in "Android SDK location" field.

(Example SDK location: C:\android-sdk; I have sub-folders like  add-ons, platforms etc under C:\android-sdk)
5. Click OK to save changes